# Mule: Unbuffered entity enclosing request can not be repeated

Tags: mule

I have a flow in which message is received from JMS, transformed, and sent to web-service (http-outbound-endpoint via reques-response pattern).

However, I get exception during outbound web-service call.

My flow looks like this:

```
<custom-transformer class="kz.scb.esb.transformation.ReportRequestRecordTransformer" name="reportRequestTransformer" doc:name="reportRequestTransformer"/>
<flow name="scb-report-request-trackingFlow1" doc:name="scb-report-request-trackingFlow1">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="${jmsOutbound.reportRequestQueue}" connector-ref="JBossMQ" doc:name="ReportRequestQueue inbound"/>
    <transformer ref="reportRequestTransformer" doc:name="Transformer Reference"/>
    <logger message="scb-report-request-tracking: #[payload:java.lang.String]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-client doc:name="SOAP client" operation="trackReportRequest" serviceClass="kz.scb.chdb.data.ReportRequestTrackingService" port="ReportRequestTrackingPortType" wsdlLocation="${httpOutbound.reporting.baseUrl}/${httpOutbound.reporting.contextRoot}/${reporting.reportRequestTracking.serviceName}?wsdl"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"   method="POST" doc:name="ReportRequestTrackingService outbound" address="${httpOutbound.reporting.baseUrl}/${httpOutbound.reporting.contextRoot}/${reporting.reportRequestTracking.serviceName}" responseTimeout="${service.timeout}" connector-ref="httpConnector"/>
</flow>
```

The exception stack trace is here:

```
2014-09-17 12:10:11,202 WARN  PhaseInterceptorChain:384 - Interceptor for {http://data.chdb.scb.kz/}ActivityTrackingService#{http://data.chdb.scb.kz/}trackActivity has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/creditHistoryDataServices/ActivityTrackingService, connector=HttpConnector
{
name=httpConnector
lifecycle=start
this=31102b0e
numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
connected=true
supportedProtocols=[http]
serviceOverrides=<none>
}
, name='endpoint.http.127.0.0.1.8080.creditHistoryDataServices.ActivityTrackingService', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={http.method=POST}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=300000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:198)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:375)
at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:235)
at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:125)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:122)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:192)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:185)
at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:184)
at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException: Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/creditHistoryDataServices/ActivityTrackingService, connector=HttpConnector
{
name=httpConnector
lifecycle=start
this=31102b0e
numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
connected=true
supportedProtocols=[http]
serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.http.127.0.0.1.8080.creditHistoryDataServices.ActivityTrackingService', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={http.method=POST}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=300000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
at org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher.execute(HttpClientMessageDispatcher.java:155)
at org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher.doSend(HttpClientMessageDispatcher.java:272)
at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:81)
at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$DispatcherMessageProcessor.process(AbstractConnector.java:2627)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
at org.mule.endpoint.outbound.OutboundResponsePropertiesMessageProcessor.process(OutboundResponsePropertiesMessageProcessor.java:39)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:50)
at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:47)
at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
at org.mule.execution.TransactionalExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalExecutionTemplate.java:69)
at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:56)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultOutboundEndpoint.process(DefaultOutboundEndpoint.java:96)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.processNext(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:162)
at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.processNext(MuleUniversalConduit.java:349)
at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.dispatchMuleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:252)
at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:194)
... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: Unbuffered entity enclosing request can not be repeated.
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:487)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
at org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher.execute(HttpClientMessageDispatcher.java:148)
... 112 more
```

What is the meaning of the error, and how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your payload after JMS Inbound ?? Is it a full SOAP request ?? Also why did you used #[payload:java.lang.String] ? instead you try #[message.payload]

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue and I'm passing a Request object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit the same request to the 'address' specified in the mule flow, through Rest Client.
If there still is some issue, then the issue is with the URL, otherwise the request and the headers which you are sending are not what the destination expects.